# Selenium with combo box control and select element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, combobox

The product which I am trying to automate has a customized combo box control from .Net.

The control is of type `<input>` and I will be able to type n search with the starting letter only.

When I try to access the `<select>` element using WebDriver , it says that the operation cannot be performed on an `<input>` field.

When i try to do a `.Sendkeys` on the `iWebElement` it will only be able to select values with starting text.

Is there any way to use WebDriver to select the combo box value using the whole text?

Sample DOM is in below format

```
<input name="icombobox_Text" tabIndex="7" title="Click to select theValue" class="ComboBox_Normal TxtBox_Css" id="icombobox_Text" accessKey="L" onkeydown="return C28.KeyDown();" onkeyup="return C28.KeyUp();" onkeypress="return C28.KeyPress();" onclick="$_('C28','TextClick')" onfocus="$_('C28','Focus')" onblur="$_('C28','Blur')" onselectstart="$_('C28','SelectStart')" onpaste="return false" oncontextmenu="return C28.KeyRightClick()" type="text" maxLength="255" maxSize="10" minSize="5" AUTOCOMPLETE="off"/>
```

There are 4 items in the combo..How to select a particular value.?

Comment: Can you post a piece of HTML containing this item? Hard to say anything unless we can see how it looks from HTML standpoint

Comment: The Select class in Selenium.UI.Support only support tag '<select>'. You have to perform action on the input tag then looking for list of options in HTML.

Comment: HTML Content added now

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

Concept:

1. The Combo Control is having Text Box + List (Drop Down image).
2. So first find the element of the drop down image by  clicking it.
3. Then use “SelectElement” Class to select the value from the list.

Sample Code:

IWebElement iWebelement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("combobox_Text"));  //Getting the element of the Text Box

IWebElement iWebelementList = driver.FindElement(By.Id("combobox_List")); //Getting the elements of  List/Drop down Box

SelectElement selected = new SelectElement(iWebelementList);  //Parsing the list

iWebelement.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown); // Clicking the drop down image

selected.SelectByText("January");  // Use select element class to select the value

Answer (score 0):

Use the following  below code, to select an Option from Drop Down:

```
IWebElement iwe = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(@class,'..item...') and contains(text(),'"+text+"')]"));           

Thread.Sleep(500);

Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
Thread.Sleep(500);

action.MoveToElement(iwe).Click().Perform();
```